# Javascript webpage search timer

Tags: javascript, html

I want to search a certain webpage for a certain string of characters. But I do not want this to be a one of search, I want the program to be constantly searching the webpage for text (the text on the webpage can change). Say maybe do a refresh and search ever minute. But I do not want the webpage to be open when doing this.

When the string of characters has been found a way of informing the user should be there as well. i.e. a text alert box.

Comment: what should happen with the search results if the page is not open?

Comment: Some form of alert is displayed to the user.

Comment: I would use an Ajax call with setInterval() determining how often you check for changes.

Comment: What about this: load the page in a iframe, keeping it hidden. Then you can refresh and check the content whenever you want

Comment: I forgot to mention that this is to be used in a chrome extension.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to "track" the changes on the remote page, you have to use the `setInterval` function that jQuery offers like below:

```
var page_contents;

setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/mypage.html',
        success: function (file_html) {
            page_contents = file_html;
        }
    });
}, 1000);  // the interval is 1 second, as you specified
```

Then you can use regular functions to perform the search in the resulted string. You didn't specified exactly what you want to do with the search results, butif you will, and you will need any help about the searching, I will provide an edit of this answer.

You have this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/barbu110/MFVK8/) that I've just created. But unfortunately, we have to deal with JSONP for external websites. But if the page you want to search in is on your server, then you will have no problem with [this](http://jsfiddle.net/barbu110/MFVK8/) code.

For your code to work with extrnal websites, those have to offer a JSONP interface, because otherwise, you will not gain access there (as it is written [here](http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/)):

> Many prominent sites provide JSONP services

Comment: I have been looking for a way to search for the characters but I can only find help on searching through textboxes and highlighting words like a "ctr+f" search. I'm not fluent in javascript, but i'm competent with computers and the logic of it. A full edit would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want something like searching a query into your text and show the number of occurances? Since you said that your page is hidden, I do not see any need of highlighting the occurances

Comment: Sorry, i wasnt very clear, I meant examples already on the internet provide solutions such as highlighting a word. I want mine to be different (hidden page using a timer NOT a textbox search). And to answer your question the set string of characters only has to occur once.

Comment: see my edit. I think this could be a good approach for your project :-)